# Implementing rounded constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a ConstraintLayout with rounded corners:

[image]

```
       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:background="@drawable/backgrond_drawable"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1.5"
            >
  
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is backgrond_drawable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="20dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#222222" />
        <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#222222" android:endColor="#222222" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

When I add a TextView to bottom of my ConstraintLayout it eliminate the roundness of corners:

[image]

what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu need to have a second drawable to make the lower corners of the textview rounded

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
                    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"/>

        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#222222" />
        <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#222222" android:endColor="#222222" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and set this drawable as the textView's background.

Or you could use a card layout and then use the textview

for eg

```
<CardView.
.
.
.
cardCornerRadius:"20dp"
>
<ContraintLayout>
<TextView>
</TextView>
</ContraintLayout>
</CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Set your TextView background transparent it will fix your issue; I hope  You can try the below approach.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/backgrond_drawable"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1.5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Testing text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```